# how to send an email verification from admin when an email is updated

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, admin

I joined a project where the code is written on django 2+.
It's a system for patient and doctors.
When a doctor registered a patient, this one gets an email confirmation with a link.
Once he clicks on it she can use the platform.

On her user interface in settings, a patient can update her email and she will get a new link to her new email to confirm that it is her email. Before she clicks on the confirmation link, the email attribute is not changed. only the email candidate is updated and to this one the email is sent.
(if I change the email attribute to the email_candidate one so if she made a mistake on the her email_candidate she won't be able to log in anymore)

Then after the click, the patient email will become the email candidate one.

All this works

on the Patient Support Admin interface, an agent can help patients to update their email also.
But when the action is requested of send an email confirmation the email candidate is not chosen. only the user email is chosen and to it the email confirmation is sent.

I really don't understand how to call maybe the same function of update email.

*models.py* **User**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager()
    
    is_physician = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    title = models.CharField(choices=TITLE_CHOICES,
                             max_length=10,
                             blank=True,
                             null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True, )
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True, )
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    home_phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                              choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
                              blank=True,
                              null=True)
    
    language = models.CharField(max_length=4,
                                choices=settings.LANGUAGES,
                                default='en',
                                blank=True,
                                null=True)
    
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True,
                              error_messages={
                                  'unique': "Email already exists."
                              }
                              )
    email_candidate = models.EmailField(
        max_length=254,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None)
    
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        unique=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(
                r'^\w+$',
                'Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                'letters, numbers and _ character.',
                'invalid'
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': "Username already exists."
        }
    )
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    ordering = ('created',)
    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
        # abstract = False
        permissions = u_perm.user_permissions
    @property
    def name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.last_name, self.first_name, )
```

*models.py* **Patient has a OneToOne field user**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    physician = models.ForeignKey(Physician,
                                  related_name='patients',
                                  null=True,
                                  blank=True,
                                  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=85, null=True, blank=True)
    country = CountryField(null=True, blank=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    reminder_hour_default = models.TimeField(
        'Send Reminder Time',
        default=settings.REMINDER_HOUR_DEFAULT)
    is_eligible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
   @receiver(post_save, sender=Patient)
   @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
   def update_status(sender, **kwargs):
    def update_patient(instance):
        # from pending/disabled to active
        current_status = instance.user.status
            instance.save()
            instance.user.save()
            return
    def update_user(instance):
        pass

    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    method_name = get_inner_method(sender)
    if instance and method_name:
        method_name(instance)
```

*models.py* **Patient Support**

```
class PatientSupport(Patient):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        # Add verbose name
        verbose_name = 'Patient Support'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Patients Support'
```

*serializers.py*   **UserSerializer with the working endpoint from the patient UI called
update_candidate_email**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permission_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    permissions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    user_messages = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'title',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'birthdate',
            'email',
            'email_candidate',
            'home_phone',
            'mobile_phone',
            'gender',
            'language',
            'username',
            'password',
            'is_patient',
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'email': {'required': False,
                      'validators': [],
                      #'read_only': True,
                      },
            'email_candidate': {'required': False,
                                'validators': [],
                                #'read_only': True,
                                },
            'home_phone': {'required': False,
                           'validators': [], },
            'mobile_phone': {'required': False,
                             'validators': [], },
            'is_patient': {'required': False},
            'username': {'read_only': True, },
        }

    

    def update_candidate_email(self, instance, validated_data, email_candidate):
        # if email candidate is None (and changed) -> search for tokens and delete token sent
        if instance.email_candidate and email_candidate == None:
            instance.email_candidate = email_candidate
            instance.save()

            ResetPasswordToken.objects.filter(user=instance).delete()
            
        # if email candidate is same to current email -> error - email in use !
        if instance.email_candidate == instance.email:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    {'email':
                     "email candidate cannot be same to current mail"}
                )

        # if email candidate is not None and already not in use-> save it (email candidate) and send new email replace_email_mail
        if email_candidate and email_candidate != instance.email_candidate:

            if User.objects.filter(email=email_candidate):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    {'email': "email in use"}
                )
            ResetPasswordToken.objects.filter(user=instance).delete()

            instance.email_candidate = email_candidate
            instance.save()

            site_domain = Site.objects.filter(name__icontains='admin').first()
            # create pass token send mail
            token = ResetPasswordToken.objects.create(
                            user=instance,)

            tiny_link = shortener.create(instance,
                                         'https://{}/api/users/verifyMail/?lang={}&token={}&region={}&patient={}'.format(
                                             site_domain.domain,
                                             instance.language if instance.language else "en",
                                             token.key,
                                             settings.REGION_PREFIX,
                                             instance.is_patient
                                             )
                                         )
            from messaging.notify import Notify
            activate(instance.language)

            msg_name = 'EMAIL_VERIFICATION'
            if not instance.is_patient:
                msg_name = 'EMAIL_VERIFICATION_STAFF'

            notify = Notify()
            notify.send_notification(
                msg_name=msg_name,
                users_pk=[instance.pk, ],
                context={
                    'tiny_link': 'https://{}/s/{}/?lang={}&region={}'.format(
                        site_domain.domain,
                        tiny_link,
                        instance.language if instance.language else "en",
                        settings.REGION_PREFIX),
                    'email_candidate': email_candidate
                })
        return
```

*admin.py*  **PatientSupportAdmin from there I need to update the email by sending an
email confiramtion to the email_candidate**

```
class PatientSupportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['pk', 'patient', 'patient_email', 'email_candidate' ]

    list_display_links = ('pk', 'patient')

   
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(PatientSupportAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(support_consent=True)

    fieldsets = (
        ('User', {
            'fields': (
                'patient',
                'get_gender',
                'birthdate',
                'home_phone', 'mobile_phone', 'language',
                'email', 'username',
                'date_modified',
                'date_joined',
                'status',
                'user',
            )}),

        ('Patient', {'fields': ('physician',
                                'country',
                                'id_number',
                                )}),

    def patient(self, obj):
        return obj.user.get_full_name()

    def patient_email(self, obj):
        return obj.user.email

    def email_candidate(self, obj):
        return obj.user.email_candidate

    def birthdate(self, obj):
        return obj.user.birthdate or ''

    def home_phone(self, obj):
        return obj.user.home_phone

    def mobile_phone(self, obj):
        return obj.user.mobile_phone

    def email(self, obj):
        return obj.user.email

    def username(self, obj):
        return obj.user.username or ''

    actions = [resend_email_verification,
               ]
```

*admin.py*  **resend_email_verification(), the one i could use but it takes only the
email still registered as user email and not the candidate email to send to
it the email confirmation**

```
def resend_email_verifcation(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for user in queryset:
        if 'users/patient' in request.path:
           
            user = user.user
          
        if user.is_patient and not user.patient.is_eligible:
            continue
        site_domain = Site.objects.filter(name__icontains='admin').first()
        token = ResetPasswordToken.objects.create(
            user=user, )
        reset_password_token_created.send(
            sender=modeladmin.__class__, reset_password_token=token)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the important part to send email in UserSerializer is

```
if email_candidate and email_candidate != instance.email_candidate:
```

You can cheat a little bit to reuse that method with a new action in admin

```
def send_verification_email_for_email_candidate(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for user in queryset:
        email_candidate = user.email_candidate
        if not email_candidate:
            continue  # defensive a little bit to ignore other use cases in UserSerializer
        user.email_candidate = f'{email_candidate}random'  # to trigger the condition above
        UserSerializer().update_candidate_email(user, {}, email_candidate)
```

But I will recommend rewriting the function or copying that logic part here instead

Comment: thanks I rewrite my function and i didn't know how to use a serializer endpoint inside admin